# Jenkinsfile junit report file path as variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, junit, jenkins-pipeline

Good day all,

I have below code in my Jenkinsfile:

```java
finally {
    try {
        sh "cat \"${report_file}\""
        junit "${report_file}"
    }
    catch (e) {
        echo "ERROR: Can't operate junit xml results'"
        echo e.toString()
    }
}
```

The result is when run is below:

```
> [] Running shell script cat
> '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace//Sanity/authenticate/keystone.json/report.junit.xml'
> <testsuites>   <!--Report is generated by Rally 0.10.1~dev35 at
> 2017-12-08T18:26:40-->   <testsuite errors="0" failures="0"
> id="" skipped="0" tests="1"
> time="15.00" timestamp="2017-12-08T18:26:17">
>     <testcase classname="Authenticate" id="" name="keystone" time="2.78"
> timestamp="2017-12-08T18:26:27" />   </testsuite> </testsuites>
> 
> [Pipeline] junit Recording test results [Pipeline] echo ERROR: Can't
> operate junit xml results' [Pipeline] echo hudson.AbortException: No
> test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

The report is there but junit step cannot read the variable. Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't specify an absolute path to the test result file. This somehow does not work with the `junit` step.

The following code **works** for me:

```java
node {
    // def path =  env.WORKSPACE + '/junit.xml'
    def path = 'junit.xml'
    writeFile file: path, text: '<testsuites><!--Report is generated by Rally 0.10.1~dev35 at 2017-12-08T18:26:40-->   <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" id="" skipped="0" tests="1" time="15.00" timestamp="2017-12-08T18:26:17"><testcase classname="Authenticate" id="" name="keystone" time="2.78" timestamp="2017-12-08T18:26:27" /></testsuite></testsuites>'
    echo path
    junit path
}
```

with output

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] echo
junit.xml
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Using an absolute `path`:

```java
node {
    def path =  env.WORKSPACE + '/junit.xml'
    // def path = 'junit.xml'
    writeFile file: path, text: '<testsuites><!--Report is generated by Rally 0.10.1~dev35 at 2017-12-08T18:26:40-->   <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" id="" skipped="0" tests="1" time="15.00" timestamp="2017-12-08T18:26:17"><testcase classname="Authenticate" id="" name="keystone" time="2.78" timestamp="2017-12-08T18:26:27" /></testsuite></testsuites>'
    echo path
    junit path
}
```

the `junit` step **fails** to find test results:

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] echo
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline/junit.xml
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, please be so kind and create a report in the [Jenkins Issue Tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org). I could not find any related entry there.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a symlink in the workspace directory to the absolute path of JUnit report worked for me.

My Workspace is /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ABC_Job_Name
And my JUnit report is in /var/jenkins_home/jobs/ABC_Job_Name/builds/10/archive/jest-junit/junit.xml

Created a symlink 'buildReports' in Workspace directory pointing to /var/jenkins_home/jobs/ABC_Job_Name/builds/10/archive/jest-junit

and using it in Jenkinsfile as

junit 'buildReports/junit.xml'